# How to call cellForRowAtIndexPath just after reloadTable

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios5

I want to create UItableView which would have 10 elements. However it create 9 (as it is visible ) and 10-th is created when that row is visible, now 1 element is destroyed (first one).

With this approach i have a problem, i would like to create all 10 row isn't important is  it visible or not and when row is visible just show it.

These rows would be recreated only when i would call reload table.

Is this possible to do ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this isn't possible. However I have a question, why you need this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- create your cells before reload,
- store them in some array,
- in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` return cells from this array,
- if you want to recreate them, simply empty the array with already created cells, create them again and call reload table

Something like this ...

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *myCells;

...

- (NSArray *)myCells {
  if ( _myCells ) {
    return _myCells;
  }

  _myCells = [NSMutableArray array];

  UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init...];
  [_myCells addObject:cell];

  ...

  return _myCells;
}

- (void)reloadMyTable {
  self.myCells = nil;
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return self.myCells.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return self.myCells[indexPath.row];
}
```